# What is the meaning of a Fermi blocking effect?

Tags: definition, neutrinos, boltzmann-equation

Given the Boltzmann equation:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_s (p,t) -H p \frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_s (p,t) \\
   = \sum_i \int \Gamma_i (p'_\alpha ,p)  f_\alpha (p'_\alpha , t) [ 1-f_s (p,t)]d^3 p'_\alpha - 
   \int \Gamma_i (p'_\alpha ,p)  f_s (p , t) [ 1-f_\alpha (p'_\alpha,t)]d^3 p'_\alpha$$

Where I am told that $f(p,t)$ is the phase-space density distribution function.

I am told that the Fermi blocking effects are taken to be negligible, but I don't know what this means.

**I have been told that it stands for $f\ll 1$ but I don't seem to find a credible source that states this. Is this true?**

**What are the Fermi blocking effects? What does it mean when they are negligible?**

Comment: Please explain your notation.

Comment: $\Gamma_i$ represents the rate of scattering production of νs corresponding
to a particular channel $i$.

$f(p,t)$ is the phase-space density distribution function for a species. (s -sterile , $\alpha$ - active).